# How to detect flash process in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, shell, flash

I'am using [this script -- lightsOn,](https://github.com/iye/lightsOn/blob/master/lightsOn.sh) to delay screensaver when flash playing.

However, the script provide only the *Chromuim* way:

```
flash_process=`pgrep -lfc "chromium-browser --type=plugin --plugin-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin"`
```

I am using the official *Google Chrome* in xfce. Not familiar with shell programming, the screenshot of my process running in *Chrome*.

[image: screenshot of my process running in *Chrome*]

I want to know how to detect the process of flash player to make this script running? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to disable xscreensaver when flash playing in Chrome.

Firstly, disable shockwave flash plugin  at '/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so' in chrome://plugins as follows:

[image: disable shockwave flash plugin]

Then the command can detect flash process in chrome:

```
flash_process=`pgrep -lfc "chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so"`
```

And I have forked the script from *github*, and push the new one with Chrome flash detection.  [Here](https://github.com/zfz/lightsOn/blob/master/lightsOn.sh) is my new script.